# I need to log off users when a value of the database is false

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I have to shutdown the app when a value of the firebase database is false, in order to give mantainance to the app whenever I want. I'm having a problem on doing this when the user is already logged in, it doesnt trigger, I have to reload the app in order for it to work. What I'm trying to do is trigger the function everytime the user acceses a page. How can I do this?

My code in typescript is this:

```
checkServerStatus() {
 this.afs.collection('settings').doc('PlatformStatus').ref.get().then(doc => {
  let status = doc.data().statusMobileApp;
  if(status){
    this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
    }
      else{
        Swal({
          type: 'info',
          title: 'Problema con Base de Datos' ,
          html: 'Error al conectarse con la base de datos. Intente mas tarde.'+
          '<br><br><div class="swalButtonContainer"><button id="btnGiveOptionsAccept" type="button" role="button"" class="customSwalBtnRed">' + 'Aceptar' + '</button>',
          showCancelButton: false,
          showConfirmButton: false,
        });
        this.userProvider.logout();
        let btn3 = document.getElementById("btnGiveOptionsAccept");
        btn3.addEventListener("click", (e:Event) => {
          Swal.close();
          this.nav.push(LoginPage);
        });
      }
    });
}
```

I have this function in the app.components.

Answer (score 0):

Rxjs can help you here. You can accomplish this by creating an [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) for whether a user is logged in or not. Then in your app.component.ts, you can subscribe to that subject and whenever the value of the subject changes, your logic above will handle the new value. 
[Here is a great tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/07/angular-7-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject) that shows how subjects can be used to communicate with components.